# Export Video using Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, flex3

Here is what I am trying to do:  A user will launch my flash application from my website.  When they do, it will ask for permission to use their webcam and then display the image coming from their webcam in my flash application.  Then, they'll be able to see themselves in the flash application on my site through their webcam.  What I'm then wanting to do is have flash record the video from the webcam and export a video file (quicktime or flv or whatever video format possible) that the user can then download to their computer.  Does anyone know if there is a way in actionscript to export video?  To be clear, I know how to do all the webcam permission and display stuff, my question is only about exporting a video from my flash application.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

A few AIR applications have been built to [generate video files form webcam recordings](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/webcam-dvr-for-apollo).  This would be a good starting point.

Here is [another really good example](http://www.joristimmerman.be/wordpress/2008/12/18/flvrecorder-record-to-flv-using-air/) with more code and steps on how the author completed it.